# Octave to LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, matlab, octave

Is there anything (command/script/function) that can convert a Octave expression to LaTeX.
What I am asking for is something like this:

I type

```
a = eye(3,3); %Identity Matrix
```

and then do something like `textify_me(a)` which produces

```
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ blah blah blah
\end{array}
```

AND/OR

```
syms x
int(sym('x^2'))
```

produces

```
\frac{x^3}{3}
```

I am not asking for "sweaving" of codes, exporting figures or anything similar. I am simply asking for conversion of variables and symbolic expressions directly to LaTeX format.

MATLAB has a function `latex` which does this. But it is closed source. Is there something Open Source or should I attempt to try and accumulate people to write it?

Comment: In the comments to this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11716/86 Jan Hlavacek explains how to get Octave to print out a matrix in LaTeX format.  It's an extremely useful comment!

Comment: I'm afraid LaTeX output is not possible with Octave. `:(` If I may suggest one application I like, it's [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/). And it has a LaTeX output, e.g. `tex(factor(x^2+2*x+1));` gives you `$$\left(x+1\right)^2$$`. `:)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all you need is a matrix, you can do this:

```
strrep(strrep(mat2str(A),",","&"),";","\\\\\n")(2:end-1)
```

where A is your matrix. That will give you the body of your matrix, without the `\begin{matrix}` and `\end{matrix}`

```
strcat("\\begin{bmatrix}\n",strrep(strrep(mat2str(A),",","&"),";","\\\\\n")(2:end-1),"\n\\end{bmatrix}\n")
```

will generate the whole thing.

I don't think there is a more comprehensive solution in Octave.

Another option seems to be using [scilab](http://www.scilab.org/products/scilab).  It is also more or less MATLAB compatible (some say even more than Octave), and it has a [prettyprint](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/prettyprint.html) function that seems to do what you want.  I have no experience with scilab, though.

Answer (score 12):

Nowadays the `latex` function is available on [Octave-Forge](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/@sym/latex.html) in the *symbolic* package.

```
>> pkg install -forge symbolic
>> pkg load symbolic

>> a = eye(3);
>> latex(sym(a))
\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right] 

>> syms x
>> latex(int(sym('x^2')))
\frac{x^{3}}{3}
```

Answer (score 4):

> But it is closed source. Is there something Open Source or should I attempt to try and accumulate people to write it?

If you aren't completely wedded to Octave, you can use [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org) to do this.

```
sage: M = matrix([[2,3],[3,2]])
sage: latex(M)
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
2 & 3 \\
3 & 2
\end{array}\right)
sage: a = integral(x^2,x)
sage: latex(a)
\frac{1}{3} \, x^{3}
```

If you really do need to do this with Octave, you can use the [Sage to Octave and back interface](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/interfaces/octave.html) as well.  I don't have a local Octave install so I can't post some code, but I don't think there should be a huge problem with the flow Octave -> Sage -> Latex.

Comment: This doesn't seem so satisfactory. At best it needs Sage, which is huge, and at worst you're suggesting switching languages entirely...

Comment: Not exactly.  Ignoring whether size is an issue these days with downloads (that depends a lot on where Nunoxic is), the same thing would work going to [an online Sage server](http://www.sagenb.org/), assuming it has Octave installed (our local one, which I can't advertise, does).  Again, untested... but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I need code compatibility with MATLAB so sage isn't the best alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately (and, to me, surprisingly), it looks like we don't have a rudimentary reverse parser yet, like we do with Maple and Mathematica.  I've opened a ticket for this at http://trac.sagemath.org/sage_trac/ticket/12467.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this great function which converts a MATLAB array to LaTeX table.
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4894-matrix2latex

Comment: This seems like a useful answer, but it can be improved by showing how it works on the example given in the question, i.e., the input for the function, the output in LaTeX code, and how the compiled table looks in a screenshot.