# Vertical addition and multiplication and long division

Tags: math-mode, macros, packages

Is there in existence packages that recreate the following environments:
[image][image][image]

Some of the above have been discussed like in the [How to present a vertical multiplication](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11702/10898) but what I am interested in is if there is a way to recreate the addition and division.

Comment: Are you also interested in displaying the "result" of the operation, as in the linked post? Or just the display of the "problem".

Comment: @Werner Both if possible. I have seen how the longdiv package for division of polynomials works and its incredibly useful to me when am writing a tutorial for my students. The display is, I suppose, a first priority and the process well I guess that would require a lot more time but if it can be done I will be thankful.

Comment: There is the `xlop` package that however uses a different way to print the schemes.

Answer (score 3):

The addition is fairly simple and examples can be found at [Numbering Vertical Addition Problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48332/numbering-vertical-addition-problems/48339#48339).

For the long division in your style you can use an `array` environment.

[image]

The MWE is shown below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
% spacing round the bracket in long division
\newcommand\divspace{\,}
\[
\arraycolsep=0em
\begin{array}{r@{\divspace}c@{\divspace}lllll}
  & & \multicolumn{4}{r}{2500.}&(answer)\\
\cline{2-6}
25&\big)&\multicolumn{4}{l}{62500.}&\\
  & &                   50&&&&\\
\cline{3-4}
  & &                   12&5&&&\\
  & &                   12&5&&&\\
\cline{3-5}
  & &                     &0&0&&
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can this be automated like the `longdiv` package.

Comment: @azetina It can possibly with LuaLaTeX to ease the pain for calculations. It will need some decent effort though.

Comment: Sincerely over the paste months I have been more interested in `LuaTex` and its variants but I still dont get the idea behind it and how to actually get to understand and even more how to use it. I here you guys here talk about it but I guess I am so much attached to just `Latex` that I have little effort to indulge in that area.

Comment: @azetina If you only going to have examples with integers, it is not too difficult via LaTeX only. If you are going to have decimals then I would use the `fp` package and life gets more complex. Glad to see these sort of things still being taught. At work at of 25 graduate Engineers __none__ can do a square root by hand:)

Comment: I guess that is the purpose of technology....

Comment: I'd write \text{ (answer)} rather than just "answer".

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sure it is better.

Answer (score 2):

The [xlop](http://ctan.org/pkg/xlop) package takes care of typesetting addition, subtraction, division, multiplication, and calculates easy functions such as gcd. However, the typesetting is French style only still (other styles are planned), for long division, stick with longdiv as suggested by azetina.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}

\begin{document}
\opadd{8}{3}

\end{document}
```

Output of the example:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While your answer might solve the problem, you should provide a visual output for a quick 'proof' as well.

Comment: Done that (adding visual proof). Thanks to @ChristianHupfer for the hint.