# How to display simply an addition in latex

Tags: math-mode

Given A, B, C *any* string or maths code, given + *any* operation of my choice, I would like to display a really simple calculation - here addition. On below the result I would like to obtain :

```
 A
+B
__
 C
```

I can't do it here, but please see the underline as right under B (not my above ugly displaying). A, B and C should be aligned. The operator is displayed on the left of B.

Actually, I am wondering if there is a package for that, to perform this simply ?

Comment: Helpful,  or possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48332/numbering-vertical-addition-problems/48339#48339

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is use the `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lS}
  & 354.42\\
  $+$& 42.1\\
  & 396.52\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

By using the `S` column of the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package, you are able to set everything accordingly to their value (unidades, decenas, centenas, etc.)

Now, regarding the line... I'm sorry, but I don't know what is the best approach.  The result of the code mentioned above is:

[image]

I just realized that you could use `\hline` or `\bottomrule` if using the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package and get something decent:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}


    \begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{lS}
      & 354.42\\
      $+$& 42.1\\
    \hline %or \bottomrule if using the `booktabs` package
      & 396.52\\
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This would be the result:

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I see what you mean, and I also thought about using tabular, but I also missed the line. I was also wondering if there was other methods which would fit with that.

Comment: @Header12 check the updated answer :).  You can use either the `\hline` or `\bottomrule` if using the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package

Comment: Thank you for your help. That's what I was looking for. Regards.