# Long division display

Tags: arrays

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

$$
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
& & & 1 & 0 & 9 & 8 & 9 \\
13 & ) & 1 & 4 & 2 & 8 & 5 & 9 \\
& & 1 & 3 \\  \\
& & & 1 & 2 \\
& & &   & 0 \\  \\
& & & 1 & 2 & 8 \\
& & & 1 & 1 & 7 \\  \\
& & &   & 1 & 1 & 5 \\
& & &   & 1 & 0 & 4 \\  \\
& & &   &   & 1 & 1 & 9 \\
& & &   &   & 1 & 1 & 7 \\  \\
& & &   &   &   &   & 2
\end{array}
$$

\end{document}
```

We all learned in elementary school how to do long division.  In standard usage one draws a horizontal line beginning at the top of the right parenthesis and underlining the digits in the quotient, but ending there rather than crossing the whole page; then one underlines the digits of each of the numbers being subtracted, again not extending the underline across the page, nor even across the whole width of the displayed mathematical notation.

I don't know how to make an underline crossing alignment tabs but underlining only the digits rather than extending across the whole width.

How can that be done?  Whoever typesets books on arithmetic must have some way to do that.

Comment: `\cline{2-5}` makes a line under columns 2 to 5

Comment: How about this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49230/1402

Comment: there's a nice example here: [Better way to display long division?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131125/579).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I just tried \cline{3-4}, and it makes a line _over_ those columns.  And the space between the line and the stuff under it is uncomfortably small. Will something else make a reasonably positioned line _under_ those columns?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Can you draw a picture of what you want? Or paste a screenshot from some book. I do not understand it. You can set your `\cline{3-4}` behind each row of your array, so there is no problem for *under* and *over*. Why do you want a line of just two columns here?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi : Look at pages 200 through 203 of this book: https://books.google.com/books?id=Ntjq07-FA_IC&pg=PA199&dq=arithmetic+long+division&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LkbBVP2tIceQyASi4IL4AQ&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=arithmetic%20long%20division&f=false

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Schriftliches Dividieren wie in der Schule ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer never have seen it with that bracket. But I guess, there have been enough good links in comments.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Nor have I... other countries other styles ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do it hard way?. Use `xlop`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xlop}

\begin{document}
\opdiv[displayintermediary=all,voperation=top]
{142859}{13}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this how you were taught to do long division?