# How can I typeset vertical addition (or multiplication) on things other than plain numbers, such as polynomials?

Tags: tables, math-mode, positioning

**tl;dr** My problem is finely positioning the operation sign.

In the examples given elsewhere ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11702) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45304), for instance), two ways of typesetting vertical arithmetic operations are given:

1. Macros from `xlop` package, such as `opmul`.
2. `matrix` or `tabular` environment.

The downside of `xlop` is that no fine tuning is possible, and the built in functionality is not fit for my use cases.

With `matrix` or `tabular`, the problem is positioning the operation sign. In all the examples I could find, the sign is placed in its own column on the left of the second of two summands. However, I would like it to be centered vertically with respect to the block of summands — so with even number thereof the sign must be positioned somewhat inbetween the lines.

If I write the operation sign before the matrix environment, like this:

```
$$ + \quad
     \begin{matrix}
         2 & 3  & 5  & 7  \\
           & 11 & 13 & 17 \\
         \hline           \\
     \end{matrix} $$
```

— It will be positioned on the vertical centerline of the box:

[image: Summation 1.]

— But if I try to add another line, or another single line matrix *(for the result)*, it will go awry:

```
$$ + \quad
\begin{matrix}
    2  & 3  & 5  & 13 \\
       & 11 & 7  & 17 \\
    \hline
    2  & 14 & 12 & 30
\end{matrix} $$
```

[image: Summation 2.]

*(The operation sign is out of vertical alignment.)*

```
$$ + \quad
\begin{matrix}
    2  & 3  & 5  & 13 \\
       & 11 & 7  & 17 \\
    \hline
\end{matrix} $$ $$
\begin{matrix}
    2  & 14 & 12 & 30
\end{matrix} $$
```

[image: Summation 3.]

*(The result is out of horizontal alignment.)*

What can be done?

Comment: "...But if I try to add another line, or another single line matrix..." -- Please be more specific about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mico I added the examples concerning the line you have quoted. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this layout you want?

*Unrelated* : don't use the plain TeX syntax `$$ ... $$` for displayed equations, use LaTeX syntax `\[ ... \]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{matrix}
\multirow{2}{*} { + }& 2 & 3 & 5 & 13 \\
   & & 11 & 7 & 17 \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
   & 2 & 14 & 12 & 30
\end{matrix} \]%

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I should look into advanced tabulation packages. Also, `\midrule` looks much nicer than `\hline`. I'm very happy.

Comment: It looks nicer mainly because `booktabs` it adds some vertical padding around the rules.