# Vertical addition and multiplication

Tags: math-mode

I am writing a thesis document in Latex and I want some text to be displayed as shown in the attached image:-

[image: Math]

I have created my own class file. I tried implementing the existing posts but couldn't modify them to get the result i want. Please guide me on this.

Comment: Did you see this related suggested on the right panel of the page? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11702/14757

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done using an `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{c@{}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}ccl}
& \makebox[0pt]{\raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$\times$}} & & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
& & & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\cline{3-6}
& & & 7 & 3 & 8 & & \text{(this is $123 \times 6$.)} \\
+& & 6 & 1 & 5 &  & & \text{(this is $123 \times 5$, shifted one position to the left.)} \\
& 4 & 9 & 2  & & & & \text{(this is $123 \times 4$, shifted one position to the left.)} \\
\cline{1-6}
& 5 & 6 & 0 & 8 & 8
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the [`arydshln`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arydshln) package one can get the double dashed line above the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\setlength\dashlinedash{5pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{2.5pt}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{c@{}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}ccl}
& \makebox[0pt]{\raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$\times$}} & & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
& & & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\cline{3-6}
& & & 7 & 3 & 8 & & \text{(this is $123 \times 6$.)} \\
+& & 6 & 1 & 5 &  & & \text{(this is $123 \times 5$, shifted one position to the left.)} \\
& 4 & 9 & 2  & & & & \text{(this is $123 \times 4$, shifted one position to the left.)} \\
\cdashline{1-6}\\[-1.09\normalbaselineskip]\cdashline{1-6}
& 5 & 6 & 0 & 8 & 8
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there some extra space between 5 and 6 in the result?

Comment: @Sigur Yes, there was. I killed it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, pour space. Didn't survive too much... lol I never imagined that the problem was that `\times`.

Comment: @Sigur Thanks for noticing that... I totally missed it ..

Comment: @Sigur I decided to give the space another chance :) Now it is in company of some companion spaces, and I think the result looks better.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, yes, nice. What about two `+` signs on the right (like `\times`) to show the addition?

Comment: @Sigur Might be. The inetrested reader can add it ;)

Comment: @Sigur On a second thought, I added it. Yes, it was in the image in the question.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, : How can i get the double dotted lines above the result as it is there in the image.... And for adding the + symbol, should i just add a & + in that command line? It is throwing an error

Comment: @ShraySharan the `+` sign has been added in the last update. For dotted lines, use the `hhline` package. I'll update the answer with the dotted line in some minutes.

Comment: @ShraySharan You're welcome. Answer updated with the dotted line. Don't forget that, if you consider an answer solved your problem, you can (after a sensible wait for other possible answers) mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The code is throwing an error: ! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \cdashline

Comment: @ShraySharan You need to load  the package `\usepackage{arydshln}`. Do you have it installed?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes sir I have it installed... Sorry i missed including the package. Is this the only way i can get a dotted line becuase it looks a little different from what i want as an output

Comment: @ShraySharan Try playing with the values `[1pt/1pt]` in `\cdashline{1-6}[1pt/1pt]\\[-\normalbaselineskip]\cdashline{1-6}[1pt/1pt]` (as I suggested in the answer) to see if you can get the desired final look. By the way, how do you expect the dotted line to be?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It's there in my question. That is how i want it to look.. The reason i want it to look similar to that is the thesis office wants us to follow the guidelines exactly.

Comment: @ShraySharan I see. I updated the answer. Is it better now?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes sir.... It looks much better... Can you please tell me how can i alter the length of this dotted line?

Comment: @ShraySharan In `\cdashline{1-6}`  the `1-6` means spanning from column `1` to column `6`. Change those values according to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

The deleted answer of A. Allet was in the right direction, but the `xlop`  package not only can make automatically the multiplication. It can also show the shifted positions,  as well as include comments with `\oplput` and `\oprput`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}
\begin{document}
\opmul[displayshiftintermediary=all]{123}{456}
\oplput(1,3){(this is $123 \times 6$.)}
\oprput(-5,2){$+$}
\oplput(1,2){(this is $123 \times 5$, shifted one position to the left.)}
\oplput(1,1){(this is $123 \times 4$, shifted two positions to the left.)}
\end{document}
```

BTW, the inserted comments can be also an automatic multiplication so any mistyping could be more evident:

[image: MWw2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\opmul[displayshiftintermediary=all]{123}{456}
\oplput(1,3){(\opmul[style=text]{123}{6})}
\oplput(1,2){(\opmul[style=text]{123}{5})}
\oplput(1,1){(\opmul[style=text]{123}{4})}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the xlop package

http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/generic/xlop/doc/xlop-doc.pdf

page 15-16