# Typesetting long division with tabular and overlining repeating part

Tags: tables, arithmetic

I used some of the solution proposed in this post:  [How to present a vertical multiplication/addition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11702/how-to-present-a-vertical-multiplication-addition)  and my code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{c*{11}{@{\,}c}}
      2&:&7&=&0&,&$\overline{2}$&$\overline{8}$&$\overline{5}$&$\overline{7}$&
$\overline{1}$&$\overline{4}$
      \\
      {\color{red} 2} &{\color{red} 0 } & &&&&&&&&& \\
      1 & 4 &&&&&&&&&&  \\  \cline{1-2}
       & 6& 0 &&&&&&&&&  \\
       & 5 & 6 &&&&&&&&  \\   \cline{2-3}
       &  & 4 & 0 &&&&&&&  \\
       &  & 3 & 5 &&&&&&&  \\  \cline{3-4}
       &  &      & 5 & 0 &&&&&& \\
       &  &      & 4 & 9 &&&&&&  \\  \cline{4-5}
       &  &      &   & 1 & 0 &&&&& \\
       &  &      &   &   & 7 &&&&& \\ \cline{5-6}
       &  &      &   &   & 3 & 0 &&&& \\
       &  &      &   &   & 2 & 8 &&&& \\  \cline{6-7}
       &  &      &   &   &   & { \color{red} 2} &{\color{red} 0} &&&
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The goal is to show the repeating decimal part with overline over the repeating decimals. The code does that, but each decimal is overlined in isolation, but I want a continuous overline!  But that does seem to infer with the mechanics of tabular ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `\multicolumn`. I took the opportunity to simplify your code, using the `array` environment in math mode:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor, booktabs}

 \begin{document}

$ \begin{array}{c*{11}{@{\,}c}}
      2&:&7&\multicolumn{8}{l}{{}=0,\overline{2\mkern1mu8\mkern1mu5\,7\mkern1mu1\mkern1mu4}}
      \\
      {\color{red} 2} &{\color{red} 0 } & &&&&&&&&& \\
      1 & 4 \\ \cmidrule{1-2}
       & 6& 0 \\
       & 5 & 6 \\ \cmidrule{2-3}
       & & 4 & 0 \\
       & & 3 & 5 \\ \cmidrule{3-4}
       & & & 5 & 0 \\
       & & & 4 & 9 \\ \cmidrule{4-5}
       & & & & 1 & 0 \\
       & & & & & 7 \\ \cmidrule{5-6}
       & & & & & 3 & 0 \\
       & & & & & 2 & 8 \\ \cmidrule{6-7}
       & & & & & & { \color{red} 2} &{\color{red} 0} \end{array} $

\end{document}
```

[image]