# Does vertical math work with complex equations?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

Does vertical math work as way to code complex equations like this:

```
{

\\\I want to vertically add line one to line two, and then show it is equal to 2(phi-1) on line three, but I can't find the way to add two stacked equations which use pi, phi or the value of e and get invalid equation messages
\\\

line one: [pi-1/2-(phi-1)-(e-1-1/2)]*2-1=0.61055367276

line two: [[pi-1/2-[[pi-1/2-(phi-1)-(e-1-1/2)]*2-1]-(e-1-1/2)]*2-1]=0.62551430473

line three: (0.62551430473+0.61055367276)/2=0.61803398874

phi-1=1/phi

phi-1=0.61803398875

1/phi=0.61803398875

π, Σ and Φ=0 as,

1/2-1=-1/2

}
```

This way of coding them is too long:

[image]

?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it is very hard to understand your question. Perhaps you are looking for `amsmath` package `align` environment then `&=`  on each row would make all the = line up?

Comment: What do you mean by "vertical math"?  "vertically add line one to line two"?  What have you tried that led to "invalid equation messages"?  What were the exact messages?

Comment: I used this code I googled:   \begin{tabular}{cccc}
  &  [\pi-1/2-(\phi-1)-(\epsilon-1-1/2)]*2-1\\
+ &  [[\pi-1/2-[[\pi-1/2-(\phi-1)-(\epsilon-1-1/2)]*2-1]-(\epsilon-1-1/2)]*2-1] \\
\hline
  & \phi-1 \cdot \frac{1}{\phi}= \\
\end{tabular}    this code was from this site, and the invalid equation message appears when entering \pi or \epsilon or \phi, and this is only when these values were used in the tabular, and irrespective of any present incorrect placement of the equal to statement. Link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11702/how-to-present-a-vertical-multiplication-addition